# Does Lock work as a boolean semaphore on a single thread?

Tags: java

I need a mutex in Java that provides exclusive access both within a single thread and across threads. Doing something very simple like this:

```
    Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Lock = " l.tryLock());
    }
```

surprising gives me true for every call:

```
Lock = true
Lock = true
Lock = true
Lock = true
Lock = true
```

Why is this, or did I fundamentally something wrong?

Comment: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says it's *re-entrant*, meaning the owning thread can reacquire it.

This is a good thing, as otherwise you could easily create a single thread deadlock.

So no it does **not** act as a boolean semaphore. If you want a boolean semaphore, use `new Semaphore(1);`. Although if you do intend to cause a self-deadlock, make sure you have another thread that can resolve it.

Comment: Worth noting that reacquire count is not infinite. Eg openjdk-8 `This lock supports a maximum of 65535 recursive write locks and 65535 read locks. Attempts to exceed these limits result in Error throws from locking methods`

Comment: Thanks. Just re-read the doc and should've been clear: "The method will return immediately if the current thread already owns the lock. This can be checked using methods isHeldByCurrentThread(), and getHoldCount()." Problem for me is that neither of those two methods are exposed to me for some reason.

Comment: @zzazzles that's because your reference is [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html), and not `ReentrantLock`.